# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Такое короткое предложение, которое идет после некоего утверждения: "Не знаю(,) почему". Правильно ли тут поставлена запятая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, запятая здесь точно не нужна, так как придаточное предложение состоит из одного относительного слова.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не ставится в сложноподчиненном предложении. придаточная часть которого состоит из одного слова. У Вас именно такой случай.

Comment: Ларf, простите, похоже, мы одновременно ответили))). Вы, конечно, правы.

Comment: Рада знакомству с Вами, пусть заочному. Вы, если не секрет, каким образом с лингвистикой связаны?

Comment: И я очень рада))). Я страстно увлекаюсь русским языком с детства. Учительница в средней школе.

Comment: Я так и знала. Мы коллеги. Школа, колледж, подготовительные курсы.